# Python regex match whole file name include file extension

Tags: python, regex

I want to fetch whole file name plus extension from a standard vsftp log file.

The file is as below:

```
Wed Aug 31 10:23:59 2017 1 ::ffff:172.18.1.168 18593420 /Shell_Scripting.sh b _ i r user1 ftp 0 * c
Wed Aug 31 10:24:18 2017 1 ::ffff:172.18.1.168 18593420 /test.txt b _ i r user1 ftp 0 * c
```

I tried regex

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\/(\w+)')
match = pattern.search(ftpfile)
print match.group(1)
```

But the only match filename(Shell_Scripting & test) not include the extension(.sh & .txt).

I tried `re.compile(r'\/(.+\.\w+)')` and `re.compile(r'\/(\w+\.\w+)')`

Both them show `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

What should be the correct regex to match the file names include file the extension?

Comment: Do not try to regex-match a filename. What about spaces? What about other funny characters, all allowed by the local filesystem? What about multiple `.ext.ens.ions`? Instead match the part up to `18593420`, then a group of `.+`, then match the `b _ i r user1 ftp 0 * c`-part.

Comment: @user2722968 Thanks for reminding. Yes, blank space should be an issue. I will try another method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension with a simple regex:

```
import re

log = """
Wed Aug 31 10:23:59 2017 1 ::ffff:172.18.1.168 18593420 /Shell_Scripting.sh b _ i r user1 ftp 0 * c
Wed Aug 31 10:24:18 2017 1 ::ffff:172.18.1.168 18593420 /test.txt b _ i r user1 ftp 0 * c
"""

rx = re.compile(r'/(\S+)')
filenames = [match.group(1) for line in log.split("\n") for match in rx.finditer(line)]
print(filenames)
# ['Shell_Scripting.sh', 'test.txt']
```

The heart is the `/(\S+)` part, which looks for a `/`, followed by at least one non-whitespace character.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your method works for most situations (multiple extension, funny characters) excluding blank space. I will keep trying to deal with the blank space. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re

s = ['Aug 31 10:23:59 2017 1 ::ffff:172.18.1.168 18593420 /Shell_Scripting.sh b _ i r user1 ftp 0 * c', 'Wed Aug 31 10:24:18 2017 1 ::ffff:172.18.1.168 18593420 /test.txt b _ i r user1 ftp 0 * c']

files = [re.findall("[a-zA-Z_]+\.\w+", i) for i in s]

new_files = [i[0] for i in files if i]
```

Output:

```
['Shell_Scripting.sh', 'test.txt']
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are only dealing with *sh* and *txt* files, you can do:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\/(\w+\.(?:txt|sh))')
```

Comment: edit: this was a response to a comment now deleted : afaik `\w` will match an underscore / does for me.